# Unity not Changing Bool Value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I am currently writing an application in C# with Unity, and I've hit a small stumbling block.  I'm trying to change the value of a `bool` in the `Update()` method of a class, but the value is unaffected by all attempts to change it.  Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ModalTextController : MonoBehaviour {
    public SpriteRenderer text;
    public GameObject objectToFollow;
    public float duration = 3.5f;
    private bool fadeOut = false;
    public bool dialog = false;
    private float startTime;

    public void FadeOut() {
        startTime = Time.time;
        fadeOut = true;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        startTime = Time.time;
        if (!dialog) StartCoroutine(waitToFade());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        float t = Time.time - startTime;
        text.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, t));

        if (fadeOut) {
            t = Time.time - startTime;
            text.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, Mathf.SmoothStep(1f, 0f, t));
        }

        // Follow the player
        Vector2 newPos = transform.position;
        newPos.x = objectToFollow.transform.position.x;
        transform.position = newPos;
    }

    IEnumerator waitToFade() {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
        FadeOut();
    }
}
```

All variables not explicitly defined in code are set via the Inspector.  I've done a bit of debugging on this, and the value only doesn't change when `FadeOut()` is called outside of `waitToFade()`.  Also, if I `print fadeOut` inside `FadeOut()`, it prints `True`, but, if I print the same value from inside `Update()`, it prints `False`.  How could I get this to return `True` from inside `Update()`?

Comment: I might have gone blind, but you're not trying to update any bool variable inside the Update() method?

Comment: You're right, I'm not changing the value of a `bool` inside `Update()`.  I am, however, trying to access the value of `fadeOut`, which is not being updated inside the method.

Comment: Iam facing a similar issue with a bool variable. Iam updating a bool to true in a function triggered for PointerEnter event. But it remains false when I try to access it in Update() method. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see the problem, but I can suggest a possible work around. Instead of calling wait to fade as a coroutine in Start(), try to do a test in Update:

if(t > duration && !dialog && !fadeOut) FadeOut();

Or you could try to make fadeOut a global variable.